# Number field and values aren't displaying

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data model

```
'Assessments': {
  'Exams': {
    'midExam': 0,
    'finalExam': 0,
  },
  'Assignments': {
    'A1': 0,
    'A2': 0,
  },
  'Tests': {
    'T1': 0,
    'T2': 0,
  },
}
```

I printed the values and prints correct:
Exams: {midExam: 0, finalExam: 0}, Assignments: {A1: 0, A2: 0}, Tests: {T1: 0, T2: 0}
The problem is I can't seem to display in the breakdown of those Maps (Exams, Assignments, And Tests)

```
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  _buildBreakdownTable('Assignments', _gradeModel.breakdown['Assignments'] ?? {}),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  _buildBreakdownTable('Tests', _gradeModel.breakdown['Tests'] ?? {}),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  _buildBreakdownTable('Exams', _gradeModel.breakdown['Exams'] ?? {}),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildBreakdownTable(String category, Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('$category Breakdown'),
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text('Assessment Type')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Details')),
              ],
              rows: _buildBreakdownRows(data),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<DataRow> _buildBreakdownRows(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    List<DataRow> rows = [];

    data.forEach((assessmentType, subAssessments) {
      if (subAssessments is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        subAssessments.forEach((subAssessmentType, subValue) {
          if (subValue is Map<String, dynamic>) {
            subValue.forEach((nestedKey, nestedValue) {
              rows.add(DataRow(
                cells: [
                  DataCell(Text('$assessmentType - $subAssessmentType - $nestedKey')),
                  DataCell(Text(nestedValue.toString())),
                ],
              ));
            });
          } else {
            rows.add(DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(Text('$assessmentType - $subAssessmentType')),
                DataCell(Text(subValue.toString())),
              ],
            ));
          }
        });
      } else {
        rows.add(DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text(assessmentType)),
            DataCell(Text(subAssessments.toString())),
          ],
        ));
      }
    });
    return rows;
  }
}

class GradeModel {
  final int finalGrade;
  final int weightAchieved;
  final String grade;
  final Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> breakdown;

  GradeModel({
    required this.finalGrade,
    required this.weightAchieved,
    required this.grade,
    required this.breakdown,
  });
}
```

I tried changing _buildBreakdownRows method, but no luck and I feel that I'm stuck at it

Comment: is it the final Map value? why you handle `else` for another non nested map ?